# Error MSB4062: The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, msbuild

So I am trying to install a Node package called better-sqlite-pool, however I am stuck with an error which I can't seem to resolve. Whenever I run **npm i better-sqlite-pool**, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets(64,5): error MSB4062: The "SetEnv"
 task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\Microsoft.Build.CppT
asks.Common.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Pu
blicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
<UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contain
s a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\Files\ScrimsBot\node_modules\integer\build\intege
r.vcxproj]
```

I have done extensive research on this, and have tried pretty much all of the suggested fixes to no success.

The first error I received I managed to fix by adding an environment variable of **VCTargetsPath** and setting it to **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140**. The error I received before doing this was the following:

```
The imported project "D:\Microsoft.
Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exist
s on disk.
```

Another thing I tried was installing the build tools using the **npm install -g --production windows-build-tools** command however that made no difference.

It is probably worth noting that I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installed with the **VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset** for desktop component installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a [rather similar issue](https://github.com/zuhito/node-red-contrib-mqtt-broker/issues/18), and got stock at the same point. I found two possible solutions [over here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24545/microsoftbuildcpptaskscommon-references-incorrect.html):

- install Visual Studio 2015 as well
- create .config file in the same dir as your exe (if you don't have it already) containing binding redirection of msbuild assemblies

The first option works for me:

- use an administrator prompt from the current user, don't elevate from a limited user, the paths will be a mess if you do that
- `npm install --global --production --vs2015 windows-build-tools`
- `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` *(this one gets stuck during the installation, ctrl-c to end it)*
- `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` *(yes, the same command again to finish the configuration)*
- `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`

Since I'm not a real programmer I wouldn't know where to begin for the latter option.

Comment: "s" missing !  It's "windows-build-tools"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need full 2015 vs you can install msbuild 2015 component https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 you might need to be sure to user the added msbuild in your path

You might use a similar command if new msbuild isn't found (even after reboot)

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;%PATH%
```

in cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

Two methods:

1. open your Visual Studio Installer, and `npm install` here:

[image]

2. Add this to the environment variables `Path`. Then run cmd as **Administrator**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```