# Ms build failing

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am running msbuild and getting the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets(64,5): error MSB4062: The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<token>' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\701\w\35jcqwcnvx\gen\tmp\src\WinNative\dll64\dll64.vcxproj]
```

Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue ?

Comment: So could you let us know what you have done or what you were doing before this error appeared? And is this issue reproducible?

Comment: Did you define the a new env variable called `VCTargetsPath`? If so, please delete it and re-build your project. Second, there is also [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569137/error-msb4062-the-setenv-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly).