# msbuild error, "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from assembly Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, sln-file

I have msbuild version 14.0.25420.1 on my win10 command prompt computer, If I try to build a visual studio project file with this command:

```
 msbuild .\folder1\WxsGenerators.sln
```

I get an error

```
BUILD FAILED


  D:\Dev\Views\YY261307_main_sv\microsoft\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.targets(40,5): error MSB4062: The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microso 
ft.Build.CppTasks.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common, Version=4.0.0.0,  
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, th 
at the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\path\TomtecWxs.vcxproj]
```

On my machine I have visual studio 2015 and visual studio 2019 installed. I need to figure out how to fix this error and build the .sln file, I've found a similar error posted here:

[Error MSB4062: The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569137/error-msb4062-the-setenv-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly)

In the accepted answer, I tried to run the npm commands but was unable to do so, the other solution `create .config file in the same dir as your exe (if you don't have it already) containing binding redirection of msbuild assemblies` I am not sure how to do

Is there any way I can understand better / fix this `"SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microso  ft.Build.CppTasks.Common` error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description you find [the solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/microsoftbuildcpptaskscommon-references-incorrect/24545) but don’t know how to bind redirect msbuild assemblies in your porject.
I can give you some suggestions about how to do that.
You can create an app.config in your project folder to bind Redirects such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You can look at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe.config` and copy necessary blocks to your app.config in project folder.